# javascript onclick function does not run all code in function

Tags: javascript

This onClick function does not run the console.log in the code snippet below, any ideas?

```
var clickFunction = function myfunc() {
 return function (){
  return console.log('here');

  }
};

<button onClick="clickFunction()"> Click here</button>
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling a function that *returns* a function. If you want to run the function that is returned you would need to do: `clickFunction()()`

Comment: thanks, will that be the same way to go if the function was async?